# How to pass a String variable to javascript onClick Function in a JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

In my jsp, I have something like this

```
<%
String isMultipleOfficesExists = (String)request.getAttribute("MultipleOfficesExists");
        String isMultipleOfficeSecurity = (String)request.getAttribute("MultipleOfficeSecurityExists");
String envParm = "default";
if("true".equals(isMultipleOfficesExists)){
    envParm = "multipleOffice";
}else if("true".equals(isMultipleOfficeSecurity)){
    envParm = "multipleOfficeSecurity";
}
%>
```

At the bottom of my form, in my submit button, I am calling a JavaScript On-click function.

```
<input class="white_button_extra_large" type="button" value="<%=goBtn%>" onclick="javascript:selectEnvironment(envParm);">
```

And my script section is :

```
function selectEnvironment(envParm)
{
    resetToken();
    logoutFlag = false;
    document.forms[0].action = contextURL+'/login/selectEnvironment?envParam=' +envParm;
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

But I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: envParam is not defined`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your envParm variable global in JSP. And your on click event should be like follows

```
<input class="white_button_extra_large" type="button" value="<%=goBtn%>" onclick="javascript:selectEnvironment('<%=envParm%>')">
```

You should pass the value from javascript function. The parameter should have value. Refer this link[Passing arguments](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_function2)